# c display adjacency list of graph

Tags: c, graph-algorithm

I have written a code for a small c graph based implementation and correspondingly listing the adjacency list of the vertices of the graph. My code for the above is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int info;
    struct node* next;
}* z, *adjv[50], *t;
void insert() {
    int j, v, e, c, d, i;
    z = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    z->next = z;
    scanf("%d%d", &v, &e);
    for (j = 1; j <= v; j++) {
        adjv[j] = z;
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= e; j++) {
        scanf("%d%d", &c, &d);
        t = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->info = c;
        t->next = adjv[d];
        adjv[d] = t;
        t = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->info = d;
        t->next = adjv[c];
        adjv[c] = t;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= e; i++) {

        while (adjv[i] != z) {
            printf("%d", adjv[i]->info);
            adjv[i] = adjv[i]->next;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    insert();
    return 0;
}
```

When I provide it with vertices =4 edges=2 and edges as (1,2) (3,4) it doesn't show this as disconnected graph as the adjacency list displays values for only 1 and 2. Please help me in correcting this problem so that the correct adjacency list can be displayed

Comment: do not use sentences with please, thanks and the like, as it just makes people have to read more (without valuable content). also use proper code indenting.

Comment: Array indices in C start at 0. You use a 1-based index consistently and your array should be big enough, but if you program in C, please use C notation. It is also not necessary to create a dummy sentinel node; the `NULL` pointer is designed to take that role.

Comment: Yes but the code is working for connected components like when v=3 e=2 (1,2)( 2,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to structure your data better. For example, at the moment, edges are represented by `struct node` and the nodes themselves are represented by an array of pointers to `struct node`.

In your code, `adjv[i]` is the head of the adjacency list for vertex `i`, but your code loops over the number of edges. You have 4 vertices and 2 edges, so you miss out on the connections to vertices 3 and 4.

A corrected (and more verbose) printing loop would loop up to the number of vertices:

```
for (i = 1; i <= v; i++) {
    while (adjv[i] != z) {
        printf("%d -> %d\n", i, adjv[i]->info);
        adjv[i] = adjv[i]->next;
    }
}
```

That said, please consider making your code more readable and more C-ish by:

- making your indices zero-based;
- using the `NULL` pointer as a sentinel value for the linked list;
- providing different structures for vertices and edges, because they represent different things and usually need different data, too;
- consistently using either one of `node` or `vertex`, because they essentially are the same thing, but should have a uniform name in your code so you can quickly understand what is going on.